# iOS self made framework can contain other third party framework ？

Tags: ios, sdk, frameworks

all:
My company now uses sereval third-party framework,now we want to make ourselves sdk ,the sdk hide all the details of the third party framework ,can this be implemented？ How I can get some information of this ?

Comment: Why do you need to *hide* anything?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you have two ways to make SDK with third part framework.

1. Rename the classes name in third part framework with prefix string. For example, `ASIHttp`, change to `MySDK_ASIHTTP`. This can prevent compile error when uses include the same third part framework in their project.
2. Don't include third part framework, just write a document which tells use to add required third part framework by themselves. This make use just have only a copy of third part framework in their project.

If you have modified the third part frameworks, I think you should use 1 method